# Add padding to sidebar

Tags: php, html, css, wordpress

I recently followed [this guide](http://www.vistaunderthesun.com/how-to-add-sidebar-in-wordpress/), to add a left sidebar to my site.

It was added successfully, but the margins and padding of the left/right sidebar and body are off, as you can see here:

[image: Website with sidebars example]

I am trying to have equal spacing between the 2 sidebars and body.

**Here is my code so far:**
[JSFiddle Example](http://jsfiddle.net/45jf0jq4/)

**CSS**

```
.site-sidebar {
    width: 300px;
    float: left;
    margin: 0 0 0 -300px;
}
.sidebar-left {
float: left;
padding: 20px 0 10px 0;
margin-left: 35px;
width: 400px;
}
```

I've adjusted all the settings in the sidebar-left part of the css with no result.

Comment: Please read the articles on [this page](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) before asking a new question in the near future.

Comment: OK - im not sure what is wrong with my post. I just read that page. Can you elaborate at all?

Comment: I really doubt you've read the entire page within 2 minutes. They explain for example that you shouldn't post your entire code, but just the relevant parts.

Comment: Im sorry -very new to this. Was hoping there would be something obvious with my css.

Comment: Just trying to clarify, you're looking for a three column layout with two narrow side columns and one main content column?

Comment: yes. i removed the left sidebar for now. but i want it to be the same width as the right and everything centered. yes youre right reddington

Answer (score 0):

I think you can solve it with the following:

```
.content-area {
    float: left;
    margin-left: 20px;
    width: 100%;
}
```

Not if you can edit the styles.css file but that's the best solution I can come up with.

Comment: Thank you for looking at this. Unfortunately that just did this http://imgur.com/dklETda. i added the calendar widget to left sidebar. and when i updated the css with that code they just ended up both on the left. its like the right widget got bumped and wrapped around to the left.

Comment: I actually think the problem is the page is not full width. I am not sure how to do this.

Comment: it actually appears there is just blank space on the right. both sidebars are appropriate width, there is just extra space on the right side.